# Add foldersize to foldername using Batch/vbs file for all subfolders in a directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, vbscript

Is it possible to add foldersize to foldername using Batch/vbs for all subfolders in a directory?

Example:
I have few subfolders in a directory like,

```
Name    --- Size
Folder1 --- (22.5GB)
Folder2 --- (980.3MB)
Folder3 --- (968.4KB)
```

Need to change folder names to,

```
Folder1 [22.5 GB]
Folder2 [980.3 MB]
Folder3 [968.4 KB]
```

I tried with the following code, it gets the folder sizes in cmd panel but need to know how to add the size to folder name,

```
@echo off
Title Get Size of Folder and its subfolders
set "Folder=C:\RootFolder\"

For /f "delims=" %%a in ('Dir "%Folder%" /AD /b /s') do ( 
    (
        echo The size of "%%a" is 
        Call :GetSize "%%a"
    )
)
For /D %%a in (*) do rename "%%a"  "%%a [!GetSize!]" 

pause

::*************************
:GetSize
(
echo wscript.echo GetSize("%~1"^)
echo Function GetSize(MyFolder^)
echo    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
echo    Set objFolder= fso.GetFolder(MyFolder^)  
echo    GetSize = FormatSize(objFolder.Size^)
echo End Function
echo '******************
echo 'Function to format a number into typical size scales
echo Function FormatSize(iSize^)
echo    aLabel = Array("bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"^)
echo    For i = 0 to 4
echo        If iSize ^> 1024 Then
echo            iSize = iSize / 1024
echo        Else
echo            Exit For
echo        End If
echo    Next
echo    FormatSize = Round(iSize,2^) ^& " " ^& aLabel(i^)
echo End Function
echo '*****************
)>%tmp%\Size.vbs
Cscript /NoLogo %tmp%\Size.vbs
Del %tmp%\Size.vbs
Exit /b
::*********************
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but not quite easy, particularly because of the arithmetics which are limited to 32-bit signed integers. Anyway, what have you tried, where are you stuck? Please read the [tour] and learn [ask] here! Regard that just requesting code for free is off-topic here!

Comment: It seems a crazy thing to do, because   1. Folders/Directories have no size, _the sum of the sizes of the file contents is what you are looking for!_   2. As soon as a single file gets modified within any directory in that tree, the name of its parent will no longer be reflective of its now modified total size sum.

Comment: The above code already shows the folder size, in proper format. Also folders get renamed, but only need to know how to call the GetSize while renaming.

Comment: Your initial metavariable, `%%a` is only for use within its own `For` loop so perform the `Ren`ame within that first loop instead of trying to do it in a new loop once that has closed. You'll certainly need to use a command to prevent the continuation of your script beyond your `pause` command and it seems absolutely crazy to create, run then delete your vbscript on each cycle of your loop.